# Microsoft AD CS - how can I see if a CA is root or subordinate?

Tags: domaincontroller, certificate-authority

I want to observe the settings of a certain CA on my domain

how it was configured and if its a root CA or subordinate

But I cannot find that information in certutil / certsrv / server manager AD CS page

Anyone knows where I can find it ?